# Book about dragons and time travel

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, dragons

I am looking for a book I read in Jr. High/High School in the late 80s to early 90s. It had to do with a dragon and his rider, a young teenage boy, who could time travel while in flight.

Sorry I can't provide more clues... It's been almost 30 yrs.

Comment: Are you certain it was a young teenage *boy* and not a girl as in the books Praxis mentioned?

Comment: @randal'thor : The main character of the third *Pern* book, *White Dragon*, is a teenage boy (Jaxom).

Comment: @Praxis Ah, I didn't know that. (I've only read the first Pern book.)

Answer (score 24):

This is one or more of the novels in Anne McCaffrey's ***[Dragonriders of Pern](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragonriders_of_Pern)*** series, which began in 1967.  The characters in these novels can travel through time while riding their dragons.

[image]

The original three novels were ***Dragonflight***, ***Dragonquest***, and ***The White Dragon***.

You most likely read ***The White Dragon***, which concerns the story of Jaxom, a young lord, and his dragon Ruth.

Comment: And probably [The White Dragon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_White_Dragon_%28novel%29)

Comment: @GerryColl : Thanks.  I was leaning to *White Dragon*, but wasn't sure.   (It's been a long time since I've read them.) I've updated the answer accordingly.  :-)

Comment: If it is Pern, The White Dragon is the most likely.  Many of the books have some time travel, but Jaxom (the teenage boy)'s white dragon is particularly good at it; he always knows "when" he is.  The pair do feature in later novels (The Renegades of Pern, for example), but they star in The White Dragon.

Answer (score 5):

You could also be thinking about *[Riftwar Saga](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/18874100-the-complete-riftwar-saga-trilogy)* by [Raymond Feist](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/18874100-the-complete-riftwar-saga-trilogy).  One of the characters becomes a dragon rider and has some ability to move differently through space and time.  These abilities come into full force in the last two books, particularly *[A Darkness at Sethanon](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/13813.A_Darkness_At_Sethanon)*.

Edit: This wiki page gives a reasonable summary of the character's story arc. (Spoilers if you haven't read the books, of course.) http://midkemia.wikia.com/wiki/Tomas_Megarson